# How to copy full form on click add button(+ plus)

Tags: javascript, html

[image]I am trying to copy full form on click add button,
copying only label name.

below JS code: below is js code trying to add form dynamically.

how to add same form below last div onclick '+' button.
using js code below, only adding panel, but it's not working.

```js
document.getElementById('add').onclick = duplicate;
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('add-form');

function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "add-form" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div class="row mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center mt-3 ml-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="add"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-xs"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center mt-3 ml-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="minus"><i class="ri-delete-bin-line mr-0"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md mt-1" id="add-form" style="width: 100%;">
    <button class="accordion btn btn-primary">Product screen</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card mt-3">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- first row -->
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 9px;">
              <div class="col-sm">
                <label for="fname">product_name              
                                    </label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="product_name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm">
                <label for="fname">price             
                                    </label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="price">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm">
                <label for="fname">pur_id              
                                    </label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="pur_id">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm">
                <label for="field2">type
                                    </label>
                <select name="field2" id="field2" class="selectpicker form-control" data-style="py-0" width="50">
                  <option selected>select one</option>
                  <option>type1</option>
                  <option>type2</option>
                  <option>type3</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

after click add button displayed only this panel.

Comment: Seems to work in the snippet I made you. The code has to be after the elements have rendered

Comment: I removed the jQuery and canvas tags

Comment: here is working, but in my local not working cause only copying `<button class="accordion btn btn-primary">Product screen</button>` these label.

Comment: What does that mean. "In my local"?

Comment: means in my local machine.

Comment: So there is an error in the console on your machine? The code works here

Comment: Please [edit] your question until it shows the same issue as the one you are seeing.

Comment: Note that you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute even before cloning, which is invalid in HTML. Cloning only exacerbates the situation. Consider removing the `id` attributes and setting the `name` attributes to signal they will have multiple values. Many server-side frameworks use `name[]` syntax to do so. You can wrap the field with the `label` element to remove the need for the `for` attribute on those elements.