# Targetting Cloned Form Input IDs for Iteration

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I've followed the answer here: [How to copy full form on click add button(+ plus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747106/how-to-copy-full-form-on-click-add-button-plus)

The functionality works as I need it to, but I need to target the cloned ID's and iterate them just like the 'add-form' ID gets iterated so i can collect their input values and input them into an email response. Currently it just uses the latest input of each and replaces as they all share the same ID.

JS

```
document.getElementById("add").onclick = duplicate;
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById("add-form");

function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "add-form" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="table" id="myTable" style="width: 100%;">
        <tr style="background-color: #E1E1E1;">
            <th style="color: #000 !important;">Service Type</th>
            <th style="color: #000 !important;">Outside<br>
            Diameter</th>
            <th style="color: #000 !important;">Thickness<br>
            of Insulation (mm)</th>
            <th style="color: #000 !important;">Single<br>
            Penetration</th>
            <th style="color: #000 !important;">Multi-Service<br>
            Penetration</th>
            <th style="color: #000 !important;">Formed<br>
            Letterbox</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="add-form">
            <td><select id="Service Type" name="Service Type">
                <option style="display:none">
                    Please select service type*
                </option>
                <option value="Plastic pipe">
                    Plastic pipe
                </option>
                <option value="Insulated metal pipe">
                    Insulated metal pipe
                </option>
                <option value="Un-insulated metal pipe">
                    Un-insulated metal pipe
                </option>
                <option value="Plastic vent duct">
                    Plastic vent duct
                </option>
                <option value="Electric cable, tray or basket">
                    Electric cable, tray or basket
                </option>
                <option value="Electrical cable trunking">
                    Electrical cable trunking
                </option>
                <option value="Conduits with cables">
                    Conduits with cables
                </option>
                <option value="CPVC sprinkler pipe">
                    CPVC sprinkler pipe
                </option>
                <option value="Gas Trac pipe">
                    Gas Trac pipe
                </option>
                <option value="Insulated plastic pipe">
                    Insulated plastic pipe
                </option>
            </select></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" id="outside diameter" name="outside diameter" placeholder="*in mm" type="text" value="'.$pb-&gt;g('outside diameter').'"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" id="thickness" name="thickness" placeholder="*in mm" type="text" value="'.$pb-&gt;g('thickness').'"></td>
            <td><select id="Single Penetration" name="Single Penetration" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="Yes">
                    Yes
                </option>
                <option value="No">
                    No
                </option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="Multi-service Penetration" name="Multi-Service Penetration" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="Yes">
                    Yes
                </option>
                <option value="No">
                    No
                </option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="Formed Letterbox" name="Formed Letterbox" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="Yes">
                    Yes
                </option>
                <option value="No">
                    No
                </option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table><!-- <div class="form-group" id="technical-row-anchor" style="background-color: #E1E1E1"></div> -->
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-light" id="add" type="button">Add Row</button>
    </div>
```

I'm fairly new to JS so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to infinitly add this form to the document, each time you click the button? Are you interested in learning a javascript (typescript) framework like angular, react or vue?

Comment: Ultimately, yes, if they have 100 variations they need, i need them to be able to do so. Its built in wordpress so using basic JQuery i believe, so any edit made to the code above would be ideal for now if at all possible.

Comment: Just a heads-up: The `id` attribute cannot contain whitespaces. And the IDs have to be unique. You should probably add an iterator to all element IDs.

Comment: Yes my mistake with the whitespacing. Thats what i need, i need all of the cloned input options to have an iterative id. The div 'add-form' has one and works as intended but i need to apply it to the inputs that are cloned but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. @agrm

Comment: Do you need to use ajax, or is it ok to have the form submitted. If the second, you can omit the `id`s and for the `<input>`s use `<input name="cables[someindex].diameter">`. Just fill out `someindex` with a number

Answer (score 0):

`duplicate ()` function only serializes the id `#add-form`. All ids that belong to the children of each `#add-form*` is identical to one another. Of course having duplicated ids is invalid HTML and you're experiencing the consequence of having such.

You can serialize each id just like how `#add-form` is:

```
clone.id = "add-form" + ++i;
// for any child element of add-form*
const lbox = clone.getElementById("letterbox");
lbox.id = "letterbox" + ++i;
```

This is a terrible idea since there a lot of elements that have unnecessary and invalid ids. A better alternative is to remove all of the ids and use the id `#add-form*` to specify what element is targeted.

```
const lbox3 = document.getElementById("add-form3").querySelector("[name='letterbox']");
// Reference the element with name="letterbox" of the third #add-form
```

As you can see using the `[name]` attribute is a little bulky, it's a little easier if you add a class to each element.

```
const lbox3 = document.getElementById("add-form3").querySelector(".letterbox");
// Referencing by class is easier to read
```

Also, many of the `#id`s and `[name]`s are invalid -- they cannot have any spaces (ex. <del>Multi-service Penetration</del> should be simpler like `multi-service`). Also, it is considered a good naming pattern to start your class, id, name, etc with a lower case letter.

**Example 1** uses standard DOM APIs to access specific elements (sans `#id`). **Example 2** uses [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements) and
[HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) interfaces to access the form controls (`<input>`, `<select>`, and `<button>` are  the form controls present in OP). Note that a `<form>` should be wrapped around everything.

### Example 1 (`#id`s removed)

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = duplicate;
let i = 0;
const original = document.getElementById("add-form");

function duplicate() {
  const clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "add-form" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}

// For demo purposes only
for (let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  document.getElementById("add").click();
}

// Collect all <tr> into a NodeList
const aforms = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

// Find the third <tr> and change the color of the text in that specific letterbox
aforms[2].querySelector('[name="letterbox"]').style.color = "red";
```

```html
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
        <tr style="background-color: #E1E1E1;">
            <th>Service Type</th>
            <th>Outside<br>
            Diameter</th>
            <th>Thickness<br>
            of Insulation (mm)</th>
            <th>Single<br>
            Penetration</th>
            <th>Multi-Service<br>
            Penetration</th>
            <th>Formed<br>
            Letterbox</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="add-form">
            <td><select name="service">
                <option selected disabled>
                    Please select service type*
                </option>
                <option>
                    Plastic pipe
                </option>
                <option>
                    Insulated metal pipe
                </option>
                <option>
                    Un-insulated metal pipe
                </option>
                <option>
                    Plastic vent duct
                </option>
                <option>
                    Electric cable, tray or basket
                </option>
                <option>
                    Electrical cable trunking
                </option>
                <option>
                    Conduits with cables
                </option>
                <option>
                    CPVC sprinkler pipe
                </option>
                <option>
                    Gas Trac pipe
                </option>
                <option>
                    Insulated plastic pipe
                </option>
            </select></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" name="diameter" placeholder="*in mm" type="text" value="'.$pb-&gt;g('outside diameter').'"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" name="thickness" placeholder="*in mm" type="text" value="'.$pb-&gt;g('thickness').'"></td>
            <td><select name="single" style="width: 100%;">
                <option>
                    Yes
                </option>
                <option>
                    No
                </option>
            </select></td>
            
            <td><select name="multi-Service" style="width: 100%;">
                <option>
                    Yes
                </option>
                <option>
                    No
                </option>
            </select></td>
            
            <td><select name="letterbox" style="width: 100%;">
                <option>
                    Yes
                </option>
                <option>
                    No
                </option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-light" id="add" type="button">Add Row</button>
    </div>
```

### Example 2 (`#id`s removed and HTMLFormElement and HTMLFormControlsCollection interfaces used)

```js
// Reference the <form>
const main = document.forms.main;
// Reference all form controls (all <input>, <select>, and <button>)
const fc = main.elements;

fc.add.onclick = duplicate;

let i = 0;
const original = document.querySelector("#add-form");

function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
  clone.id = "add-form" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
  original.parentElement.append(clone);
}

// For demo purposes only
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  fc.add.click();
}

// Reference all [name="letterbox"]
const lboxes = fc.letterbox;

// Change the color of the text of the third [name="letterbox"]
lboxes[2].style.color = "red";
```

```html
<form id="main">
  <table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr style="background-color: #E1E1E1;">
      <th>Service Type</th>
      <th>Outside<br> Diameter
      </th>
      <th>Thickness<br> of Insulation (mm)</th>
      <th>Single<br> Penetration
      </th>
      <th>Multi-Service<br> Penetration
      </th>
      <th>Formed<br> Letterbox
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="add-form">
      <td>
        <select name="service">
          <option selected disabled>
            Please select service type*
          </option>
          <option>
            Plastic pipe
          </option>
          <option>
            Insulated metal pipe
          </option>
          <option>
            Un-insulated metal pipe
          </option>
          <option>
            Plastic vent duct
          </option>
          <option>
            Electric cable, tray or basket
          </option>
          <option>
            Electrical cable trunking
          </option>
          <option>
            Conduits with cables
          </option>
          <option>
            CPVC sprinkler pipe
          </option>
          <option>
            Gas Trac pipe
          </option>
          <option>
            Insulated plastic pipe
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control" name="diameter" placeholder="*in mm" type="text" value="'.$pb-&gt;g('outside diameter').'"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" name="thickness" placeholder="*in mm" type="text" value="'.$pb-&gt;g('thickness').'"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="single" style="width: 100%;">
          <option>
            Yes
          </option>
          <option>
            No
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="multi-Service" style="width: 100%;">
          <option>
            Yes
          </option>
          <option>
            No
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="letterbox" style="width: 100%;">
          <option>
            Yes
          </option>
          <option>
            No
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-light" id="add" type="button">Add Row</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The first example gave an error and said 'clone.getElementByID("letterbox")' isn't a function.

With the name selector, where would i place this, and would i have to create a long list of those for eah i.e. lbox1, lbox2, lbox3 etc or is there a way to iterate it automatically? @zer00ne

Comment: The "D" is actually "d" in `.getElementById()`. Yeah, a huge list that's why I consider it a horrible idea, but it's feasible if you don't mind code bloat. Your best recourse is to remove all of those ids and just use the `<tr id="add-form*">` as the reference point to the rest of the table cells and form controls. I just updated my answer with another way to access the DOM, see **Example 2**